# How to clean 'Iron removal filter'?

Tags: cleaning, water

In water purifiers, the iron removal filter needs to be cleaned every 3 months by striking it continuously with something hard along with the backflow of water. But this technique is really tiresome and takes much effort and time. Is there any easier and faster way to do this?[image: I have added the image of the iron removal filter. It's closed at both the ends and can't be opened.]

Comment: Can you please specify the type of water purifier? They can range from a simple Britta to an industrial purifier, thus can't give a specific answer. In household types, as far as I know, you can just replace the filters every 6 months depending on the usage.

Comment: I'm asking about how to clean not to replace.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question of, What type of water purifier do you have? If you can specify the model, the use and approximate size and capacity, it will be more help for people to actually answer your question.

Comment: Model is "Kent Maxx- UV + UF Purification" and in the iron removal filter its written 'Birm media inside'. Anything more do I need to specify?

Comment: Weight: 6kgs and Product dimension(mm): 390(L)*285(W)*400(H)

Comment: Is that limescale? Have you tried to clean it with baking soda?

Comment: @ott-- I have added the image of the iron removal filter. It's closed at the two ends and can't be opened. Please help me out if you know how to clean it without striking it continuously.

Comment: Please post the manufacturer's recommended instructions for the "cleaning procedure." I can find nothing online to recommend a better hack. Is the filter supposed to be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

The filter you show for the unit you have **cannot be cleaned for reuse**.

It is replaceable and should not be reused due to the chemical action of the filters construction. It cannot be reversed mechanically for reuse. The filter is not simply a mesh kind of screen that can be flushed clean. Attempting to do as you wish will compromise the filter effectiveness possibly making your whole filtration unit unusable. The spent filter is a consumable and must be discarded according to the manufacturer's recommendations and replaced with a fresh filter.

Using chemicals that are not approved for the filter can have unexpected consequences. The filter can be destroyed. The unit that holds the filter can become unusable. Lastly, you could hurt yourself by ingesting toxic chemical residue.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this three times, once for each paragraph.

Comment: @ZeissIkon What a kind thing to say! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I shall try to respond to the only familiar words in the question: ***tiresome***, ***effort***, ***time***, and my favourite word ***easier***. I think that the word efficient may not apply.

*Disclaimer*: I cannot say much about the backflow of water. If you have to reverse the filter between two pipe fittings, and put it back into the water line, I don't understand. …
If you are talking about pouring some water into the back end with a funnel, say, that's different.

It's an iron filter. Perhaps a ***strong rare-earth magnet*** dropped into the open end of the water filter, withdrawn using a string, remove iron particles from the thing, and repeat.

It's a pain to sit there under the sink with a heavy spoon whacking the filter. Perhaps ***a strong electric vibrator*** can be fastened to the side of the filter to do the whacking for you.

An old-fashion ***heavy-duty fire alarm bell*** has an electro-magnetic clapper that can out-tap you 1000 times better. Get one at a salvage store, remove the noisy bell and let the little ball bang away.

If you have ***a hammer-drill***, you can make a collar from a steel adjustable ring, make and attach a collet to go into the drill chuck and let the drill hammer away at the filter.

Comment: This answer was given before I had information about the filter to do some research online from the manufacturer. Please see later answer which I believe is correct and true.

Answer (score -1):

Try the dishwasher! If it is small enough, I would suggest the silverware section. Pros: Super easy and fast. Cons: can't iron for a while (shucks) and possibly faster deterioration of the plastic.

> Note: I have never tried this before. If the filter feels flimsy (ie: the plastic or mesh) enough that it may be wrecked by putting it in the dishwasher, DON'T try this.

Comment: Wouldn't this hurt the dishwasher filter?

Comment: There is no way a dishwasher or its detergent can clean this kind of filter.  It's that simple.

Answer (score -1):

If the filter is trapping iron oxide (rust) particles, then the following describes a chemical means of clearing the filter.

Oxalic acid's main applications include cleaning or bleaching, especially for the removal of rust (iron complexing agent). Bar Keepers Friend is an example of a household cleaner containing oxalic acid. Its utility in rust removal agents is due to its forming a stable, water-soluble salt with ferric iron, ferrioxalate ion.

Comment: Oxalic acid is also toxic -- it's what makes rhubarb leaves poisonous, and the metabolic product of ethylene glycol (antifreeze) that makes that substance toxic.  Not a good thing to put where drinking water will go...